# Suppose $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$ and that $|a|<1$ . Prove that the sequence $\{a_n^n\}$ converges to $0$ .

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Can I write "By the Polynomial Property, if the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$, then for the polynomial $p=(a_n)^n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
$\mathop{\text{lim}}\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_n)^n=a^n$. By Proposition 2.28, if $|a|<1$, then $\mathop{\text{lim}}\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} a^n=0$.
Therefore, the sequence $\{(a_n)^n\}$ converges to 0"? Can I use the limit twice?

Comment: doesnt seem too rigorous to me. It feels kind of like the classical example of $(1+1/n)^n$ converges to $e$ but not $1$

Comment: God you're right. Thank you I'll rewrite

Comment: Are we all supposed to know the contents of proposition 2.28?

Comment: For $n$ large enough, $|a_n| < \frac{1+|a|}{2}$, so that for $n$ large enough,  $|{a_n}^n| < ...$

Answer (score 1):

$\underline{\text{Preliminary Result}}$ 
**Lemma-1** 
For $~\displaystyle 0\leq B < 1, ~\lim_{n\to +\infty} B^n = 0.$ 
**Proof**
Without loss of generality, $~B > 0.~$ Let $~M~$ denote $~\log(B) \implies M < 0.$ 
For any $~\epsilon~$ such that $~0 < \epsilon,~$ let $~S~$ denote $~\log(\epsilon).~$ 
Choose $~N \in \Bbb{Z^+}~$ such that $~N > \dfrac{S}{M} \implies~$ for all $~n > N, ~n > \dfrac{S}{M} \implies $ 
$Mn < S \implies \log(B^n) < \log(\epsilon) \implies B^n < \epsilon.$

---

Note that in general, for $~x\in \Bbb{R}, ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},$ you have that $~|x^n| = |x|^n.$

**To Prove** 
For all $~\epsilon > 0, ~\exists ~N \in \Bbb{Z^+},~~$
such that $~~\forall n > N, ~|a_n|^n < \epsilon.~$

First, for simplicity, assume that $0 < a < 1.~$

Set $~\epsilon_0~ = \min\left( ~\dfrac{a}{2}, \dfrac{1 - a}{2} \right).$

The necessary result will be proven for any $\epsilon_1~$ such that $~0 < \epsilon_1 < \epsilon_0.~$ This will then establish the result for any $~\epsilon > 0,~$ since if the result holds for any $~\epsilon_1,~$ it must also hold for any $~\epsilon > \epsilon_1.$

Define $~T(\epsilon) = (a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon) \implies T(\epsilon_1) \subseteq T(\epsilon_0) \subseteq (0,1).$

From the premise, $~\exists ~N_1 \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ such that $~\forall n > N_1, ~a_n \in T(\epsilon_1).$

Set $~B = a + \epsilon_1 \implies 0 < B < 1 \implies $ 
[by Lemma-1] $~\exists ~N_2 \in \Bbb{Z^+}~$ such that for all $~n > N_2,~ B^n < \epsilon_1.~$

Set $~N = \max(N_1,N_2),~$ and consider any $~n > N.~$

Then $~a_n \in T(\epsilon_1) \implies 0 < a_n < B < 1  \implies 0 < (a_n)^n < B^n < \epsilon_1.$

So, the result is established for $~0 < a < 1.$

---

Without loss of generality, $~a \neq 0,~$ else the result is trivial.  Suppose that $~-1 < a < 0.~$ Then define $~c = -a \implies 0 < c < 1.~$

Set $~\epsilon_0~ = \min\left( ~\dfrac{c}{2}, \dfrac{1 - c}{2} \right).$

Define $~W(\epsilon) = (a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon) \implies W(\epsilon_1) \subseteq W(\epsilon_0) \subseteq (-1,0).$

Also, define $~T(\epsilon) = (c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon) \implies T(\epsilon_1) \subseteq T(\epsilon_0) \subseteq (0,1).$

Define $~N_1, N_2, N,~$ and $~B~$ analagous to how they were defined in the previous section, but against the value $~c > 0.~$

Then for any $~n > N,~$ you have that $~a_n \in W(\epsilon) \implies (- a_n) \in T(\epsilon) \implies 0 < |a_n|^n = |- a_n|^n < B^n < \epsilon_1.$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the statement "$\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n)^n = a^n$". You cannot take the limit as $n\to\infty$ but keep one of the $n$'s in your sequence fixed. It also does not make sense that the RHS $a^n$ depends on $n$, which is the limiting variable.

What you want to do instead to solve this exercise is the definition of $a_n\to a$. Since $|a|<1$, we find $\varepsilon>0$ such that $0< 2\varepsilon < 1-|a|$ (why?). Apply the definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$ to this $\varepsilon$. Can you bound $(a\pm \varepsilon)^n$ and conclude?